# Unable to understand the output for the C code

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    printf("%d \n"+1,a);   // output : d
    printf("%%d \n"+1,a);  // output : 5
    printf("%q \n"+1,a);   // output : q
    printf("%%q \n"+1,a);  // output : q
    printf("%k \n"+1,a);   // output : k
    printf("%%k \n"+1,a);  // output : k
    printf("ABCD \n");     // output : ABCD
    printf("ABCD \n" +1);  // output : BCD
    printf("ABCD \n" +3);  // output : D
}
```

I am unable to understand the output given by the above program. I am a newbie. May be if i had to know advanced topics in pointers??

Comment: Even `printf("ABCD \n");     // output : ABCD` too ?

Comment: Your code has things to do with `pointers` itself!

Comment: No issue with  printf("ABCD \n");     // output : ABCD   @P0W .

Answer (score 7):

`"%d \n"+1` returns a pointer pointing to the space containing `"d \n"`. Similarly, `"%%d \n"+1`  returns a pointer pointing to `"%d \n"`.

Therefore, the statement

```
printf("%%d \n"+1,a);  // output : 5
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d \n", a);
```

That's why it outputs 5.

As for `"%%q \n"+1` which is equivalent to `%q \n`, `%q` is not a predefined format specifier, and the behavior is undefined (refer to [C1X](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) page 315).

The answers to the other statements are similar.

Comment: BTW,you didn't mention about either of this `printf("%%q \n"+1,a);  // output : q` OR this `printf("%%k \n"+1,a);  // output : k`.These aren't predefined modifiers,please include the reason for them too.Though,I have already upvoted your answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Analyzing `printf("%d \n"+1,a)`:**

- The first argument passed to `printf` is the address of a string in memory
- This string contains several ASCII characters, and ends with a 0 character
- In your case, you are passing the address of the string `"%d \n"` + 1
- So the first character that `printf` "sees" is `'d'` (instead of `'%'`)
- As a result, you are printing `"d \n"` and the argument `a` is ignored

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%%d \n"+1,a)` is equal to `printf("%d \n",a)` so it is printing `5`.

`printf("ABCD \n" +1);` here compiler will read from place 1 that is B so it is Equivalent to `printf("BCD \n" );`

```
printf("%d \n"+1,a);   // output : d   here compiler reads d\n 

printf("%%d \n"+1,a);  // output : 5  here compiler reads %d\n

printf("%q \n"+1,a);   // output : q   here compiler reads q\n 

printf("%%q \n"+1,a);  // output : q   here compiler reads %q\n 

printf("%k \n"+1,a);   // output : k   here compiler reads k\n 

printf("%%k \n"+1,a);  // output : k    here compiler reads %k\n 

printf("ABCD \n");     // output : ABCD    

printf("ABCD \n" +1);  // output : BCD  here compiler reads BCD\n 

printf("ABCD \n" +3);  // output : D  here compiler reads D\n
```

Comment: Please don't repeat answers which have been previously mentioned.Rather you must support them by upvoting for them.Else,all your this effort may turn opposite to gain you downvotes rather than expected upvotes!

Comment: @shekharsuman i was constructing My  answer. well Point taken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is to do with pointers. If those `ABCD` string constants were assigned to local variables, it would look like this:

```
char* s = "ABCD";
```

The `s` variable is a pointer to the first character of the string, the A. The `printf` function prints from the pointer it is given until the end of the string.

Pointers have a type, here it is `char`. If 1 is added onto a pointer, the resulting pointer points to the old memory address plus the size of the type of the pointer. So adding 1 to a pointer to the A in ABCD redults in a pointer to B. When that gets passed into printf, it again prints to the end of the string, starting from the B.

That should be enough to explain the other output too.

Comment: No,seriously,this is not enough!

Answer (score 0):

printf takes a const char* pointer. The strings you have used are string litterals which are constants stored in your program from start. You then pass in a pointer to the start of the string to printf. But when you do +n, you do pointer arithmetic. The compiler knows that you have a type of char and increments the pointer value with one. which means that the first n chars are never seen by printf.

For example if "ABC" starts at address 100, B will be on address 101,  C on 102, and a hidden 0 (end of the string)  on 103. The compiler will interpret "ABC" + 1 as 100+1, and pass 101 to printf, which will happily work with the string starting at address 101. thus printing "BC"